# What is the basic idea behind calculation of area?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, mathematical-logic, mathematics-social-history

The system of calculating area in terms of square units is pretty philosophical and not very intuitive. It must have taken a great amount of time for humanity to arrive at such a convention and to spread it across different societies.
My question is about finding basics of such a convention and should the person who first thought of calculating areas in square units be regarded a great philosopher equivalent to Newton and Einstein?
Moreover, could we have evolved a different method of calculating areas?

Comment: I strongly suspect no one knows or will ever know, but my guess is that something like this probably arose many times independently, sometimes perhaps spreading a bit before being forgotten (war, famine, sickness, etc. killed off most of those in some region who utilized this), and eventually at some point spreading sufficiently to survive until written records. The idea seems reasonably discoverable to me, however, especially after the growth of agriculture, since it's a small step to use square units to measure the size of fields once you have rows of crops in front of you.

Comment: It is unclear to me why you find the idea of area in terms of square units to be unintuitive. This corresponds to the definition of area of a square as the product of the two sides of the square which, presumably, goes back to over 4000 years ago.

Comment: Maybe consult: Steven A. Treese, "Historical Area". In *History and Measurement of the Base and Derived Units.* New York: Springer 2018, pp. 301-390. From the abstract: "Area units appropriate for everyday use were most commonly squares of linear measurement units, but have also been separately defined and had their own, unique unit names. This chapter describes the roots and approaches to area measurement and calculation which have been applied over the centuries. The development of the concepts of land ownership and agriculture that drove the definitions of larger area units is discussed."